# How to get google map real time location in another activity

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api-client

Let's say I can get my location real time in a fragment and now I have another activity I need to get the real time location from this mapTabFragment and how can i do this. since I already have my real time location in this fragment all i wanna do is use this result in my another activity. i just need the latlng ...

```
public class MapTabFragment extends Fragment implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener{

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    List<ParseObject> parseObjectsList;
    ArrayList<Post> postsList;
    private static int REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES = 200;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_tab, container, false);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
     //   mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        postsList = new ArrayList<>();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        //connect here or at onStart()?
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

       // buildGoogleApiClient();
        if(checkGooglePlayServices()){
            buildGoogleApiClient();
        }
        createLocationRequest();
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        //  mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }


    private boolean checkGooglePlayServices() {
        int checkGooglePlayServices = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getContext());
        if (checkGooglePlayServices != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            /*
            * google play services is missing or update is required
            *  return code could be
            * SUCCESS,
            * SERVICE_MISSING, SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED,
            * SERVICE_DISABLED, SERVICE_INVALID.
            */
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(checkGooglePlayServices,
                    getActivity(), REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES).show();

            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES) {

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Make sure the app is not already connected or attempting to connect
                if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() &&
                        !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Google Play Services must be installed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //finish();

            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
            Log.d("map","Google_Api_Client: It was connected on (onConnected) function, working as it should.");
        }
        else{
            Log.d("map failed","Google_Api_Client: It was NOT connected on (onConnected) function, It is definetly bugged.");
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }

//        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
//                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Latitude:" + mLastLocation.getLatitude()+", Longitude:"+mLastLocation.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    protected void createLocationRequest(){
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(20000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates(){
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Latitude:" + mLastLocation.getLatitude()+", Longitude:"+mLastLocation.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }




    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    }

    protected void stopLocationUpdates(){
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

//    @Override
//    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
//        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
//        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
//        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
//        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
//
//        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().
//                getSystemService(getContext().LOCATION_SERVICE);
//        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
//        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
//        if (location != null) {
//            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
//                    new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 15.0f));
//            //     mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude())).title("hoodmark"));
//
//            //Initialize Google Play Services
//            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
//                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
//                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
//                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//                    buildGoogleApiClient();
//                    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
//                }
//            } else {
//                buildGoogleApiClient();
//                mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
//            }
//
//        }
//        new GetPostsDataTask().execute();
//    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
  //      mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

    public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);

            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }

    /***
     * Mango code to handle getting posts Top1000 in area based on likes
     * as well as getting users location and
     */
    /**
     * TODO: query parse for the top 100 posts
     * @param longitude
     * @param latitude
     * @return
     */

    public ArrayList<ParseObject> getTop100PostsForLocation(double longitude, double latitude) {
        ArrayList<ParseObject> top100Posts = new ArrayList<>();

        return top100Posts;
    }
```

LogCat:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzj.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown Source)
at com.mangoconcepts.hoodmarkandroid.fragments.MapTabFragment.startLocationUpdates(MapTabFragment.java:203)
at com.mangoconcepts.hoodmarkandroid.fragments.MapTabFragment.onConnected(MapTabFragment.java:184)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk.zzk(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzj.zzi(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzh.zzpx(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzh.onConnected(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzl.onConnected(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzc.onConnected(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzg.zzqL(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzc.zzqN(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to check your google Client api if its enabled or not . check this for more information :https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/android

Comment: thank you and i checked my code suddenly find out i kind of call connect api client 2 times. thank you!